# How do you persist an instantiated nested form object when creation fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, nested-forms

I have models `Software` and `Version`. A Software `has_many` Version's and `has_one :first_version`

```
class Software < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :versions
  has_one :first_version, -> { order(created_at: :asc) },
                          class_name: "Version", dependent: :destroy 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :versions
end

class Version < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :software
end
```

I'm building the nested object in the `new` controller action.

```
class SoftwaresController < ApplicationController
  
  def new
    @software = current_account.softwares.build
    @software.build_first_version
  end

  def create
    @software = current_account.softwares.build(software_params)
    if @software.save
      redirect_to software_path(@software)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def software_params
    params.require(:software).permit(
      :name,
      first_version_attributes: %i[id release_date],
    )
  end
end
```

form:

```
  <%= simple_form_for :software do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>


    <%= f.simple_fields_for :first_version do |v|%>
      <%= v.input :release_date %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

With the above code, if something fails during creation, the nested object is persisted even though the object itself and it's parent do not have an `id` yet, and so errors are displayed under each field with invalid values.
At the same time, if I comment out the line where I build the nested object, the form does not break, just no nested fields are displayed. **This is good.**

Now, because the form is reused in the `new` and `edit` views and I don't want to let users edit the `:first_version` through this form nor rely on the view to render it conditionally if `@software.new_record?` I put the nested object in a global variable and point the nested form to that variable hoping that the same result will be achieved in the `edit` view because no global variable will exist.

```
  def new
    @software = current_account.softwares.build
    @first_version = @software.build_first_version
  end
```

form:

```
  <%= simple_form_for :software do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>


    <%= f.simple_fields_for @first_version do |v|%>
      <%= v.input :release_date %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**Problem:**
If something goes wrong during creation the object is no longer persisted and the view breaks due to `@first_version` being `nil`. So why is the nested object persisted when I do `@parent.build_nested_object` but not when `@nested_object = @parent.build_nested_object` ?

Answer (score 0):

Solving the problem by creating more `i_vars` can lead to bugs. I think the best option is to disable the field based on a condition and change your view to the following.

```
  <%= simple_form_for @software do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for @software.first_version || @software.build_first_version do |v| %>
      <%= v.input :release_date, disabled: (true if @software.first_version.id) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Using this view means that you can initialize only `@software` on your controller.

```
class SoftwaresController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @software = current_account.softwares.build
  end
end
```